# Docker CMD cannot add new user, permission denied

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I have a docker image that at the end launch this script:

```
# Start the server
CMD [ "bash", "/app/start.sh"]
```

And then my script `start.sh`

```
# Create ssh user
useradd -m -d /home/${SSH_MASTER_USER} -G ssh ${SSH_MASTER_USER} -s /bin/bash
echo "${SSH_MASTER_USER}:${SSH_MASTER_PASS}" | chpasswd
echo 'PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin"' >> /home/${SSH_MASTER_USER}/.profile
```

And I keep getting this error:

```
useradd: Permission denied.
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
```

If run with sudo it says:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Tried to fix it like this:

```
sudo -S useradd -m -d /home/${SSH_MASTER_USER} -G ssh ${SSH_MASTER_USER} -s /bin/bash
```

But now is asking me for a password, but there is not password...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved by adding my existing user to the sudo group:

```
RUN echo "myUser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/docker && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/docker
```

then the:

```sh
sudo -S useradd -m -d /home/${SSH_MASTER_USER} -G ssh ${SSH_MASTER_USER} -s /bin/bash
```

worked without password

Answer (score 1):

my base image is using root.
so i am adding `appuser` and installing sudo like this:

```
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y sudo
RUN echo "appuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/appuser && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/appuser
```

Later on when you ready to use new user for all commands:

```
USER appuser:appuser
```

that is it, now `appuser` which is going to be user by default can use `sudo` without password.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Instead of creating a new user I have added the existing user to the sudo group. For some reason the `CMD` script was running with that user